# Query give zero output

Tags: mysql

I am trying to filter results with a drop down and have it displayed in a table. In theory my query below should pick up all data that is requested,but I get zero results. Maybe I am looking at this for way too long. What am I doing wrong.

```sql
SELECT ac.route, ac.page_number, ac.link_number, ac.address, di.type, 
pa.file_code, pb.member_id 

FROM digital di, ips_trans ip, members pa, 
files ac, publication pb 

WHERE Date_Format(di.date,'%Y-%m-%d') = Date_Format(ip.roll_date,'%Y-%m-%d') 
      AND Date_Format(di.date,'%Y-%m-%d') = Date_Format(pa.date,'%Y-%m-%d') 
      AND di.payment = pa.paymentnow 
      AND ac.page_number = ip.code_number
      AND ac.phone_number = pb.cell_number
```

Comment: You get 0 result and no error ?
Anyway, start by putting a space between **Date_Format(pa.date,'%Y-%m-%d')** and **AND di.payment**
And we know nothing about your tables, your schema...

Comment: Okay you are correct I gave no information about my tables or schema. I am using Mysql by the way. However, thank you for you input on the code.

Comment: So if you have no error (check with mysqli_error()), it means one of your condition is not met. Start by removing them one by one until you find the culprit. (I knew for mysql since you tagged it as mysql :) )

Comment: Thanks I found the issue in di.date there were no dates that matched with pa.date so I inserted a date that matched and got the info. Now I have a new issue. I ran the following query below and keep getting the same record over  and over again. I put a limit 30 but all the same record.                                                                                                     WHERE Date_Format(di.date,'%Y-%m-%d') = Date_Format(ip.roll_date,'%Y-%m-%d') 
      AND Date_Format(di.date,'%Y-%m-%d') = Date_Format(pa.date,'%Y-%m-%d') limit 0,30;